# Does $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{\sqrt {n^2+n}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Just a question on the convergence of $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{\sqrt {n^2+n}}$$ Does it converge? If so, what to?

It's not immediately obvious to me whether or not the series does converge. I don't know that I can apply any of the tests I know of.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: "It's not immediately obvious to me whether or not the series does converge". $\displaystyle \frac1{\sqrt {n^2+n}}\sim \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Observe that $\sqrt{n^2 + n} \leq \sqrt{n^2 + n^2} = \sqrt{2} n$ and use the comparison test.

Comment: Thanks. Really don't know how I missed this.

Answer (score 11):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\frac1{\sqrt {n^2+n}}\ge \frac1{\sqrt {n^2+n^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}\:n}, \quad n \ge1.
$$

Comment: Yeah, not sure what was going on in my head this is easy. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{\sqrt {n^2+n}} \geq \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{\sqrt {n^2 + n + 1/4}} = 
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{n + 1/2}
$$

Comment: I'm such an idiot. Not sure how I missed this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to see it (this method is not that substantial, though; just for your reference):

We have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+n}} = \frac{1}{n\sqrt{1 + 1/n}} \sim \frac{1}{n}
$$
as $n \to \infty$;
hence by the limiting comparison test and by the fact that the series $\sum_{n}1/n$ diverges, we conclude that the series under consideration diverges.